# Zsh vi copy mode selection - character under cursor is not highlighted

Tags: zsh, highlight, vi

If I switch to copy mode in zsh (vi mode), and begin selecting text using v, the character that is directly under the cursor is never highlighted properly even though it is selected (i.e. if I copy the selection, that character shows up in the pasted text).

I want zsh to properly highlight all selected characters, including the one under the cursor just like in vim. How can I do that?

Here is the highlighting/color portion of my `.zshrc` file

```
autoload -U colors && colors    
PS1="%B%{$fg[red]%}[%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$fg[red]%}@%{$fg[red]%}%M %{$fg[red]%}%~%{$fg[red]%}]%{$reset_color%}$%b "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `region` parameter of `zle_highlight` array by adding this line to your `.zshrc` configuration:

`zle_highlight=('region:bg=168,fg=251')`

Adjust the colors to your liking.

Read more about character highlighting in zsh [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Character-Highlighting).

Comment: Thanks, this works! One thing I noticed however is that the highlighting is still off after pasting text (character under cursor of pasted text is not highlighted).

Comment: @WalksB, `zle_highlight` array also has `paste` parameter. You can specify more parameters for `zle_highlight` array as follows:
`zle_highlight=('paste:bg=168,fg=251', 'region:bg=168,fg=251')`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a cursor not being highlighted in visual vi mode.

I found [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) plugin and I was interested if this was fixed or workaround in this plugin. It wasn't by default, but I made some tests and [tweaks with highlighters](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/master/docs/highlighters.md#how-to-tweak-highlighters) and it worked!

I added the following configs in my `.zshrc` and the cursor started to be highlighted in visual vi mode:

```
source ~/.config/zsh/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh

# zsh-syntax-highlighting
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_HIGHLIGHTERS=(main brackets pattern regexp line cursor)

typeset -A ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[cursor]=bg=white
```